# Converting field type while aggreagtion in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a set of documents on which I would like to perform aggregations: sum the values of 'sessions' field . field type of 'sessions' is string and while performing aggregation it has to be converted to an integer field.

Ex document:

```
{

"bounceRate": "100.0",
"avgSessionDuration": "0.0",
"sessions": "1",

}
```

My query:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "total_sessions": {
      "sum": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "Float.parseFloat(doc['ga:sessions'].value)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
{
"error": {
"root_cause": [
{
"type": "script_exception",
"reason": "failed to run inline script [Float.parseFloat(doc[sessions'].value)] using lang [groovy]"
}
],
"type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
"reason": "all shards failed",
"phase": "query",
"grouped": true,
"failed_shards": [
{
"shard": 0,
"index": "testindex",
"node": "0Kgq1cQKT2OvFSGu5E6ptw",
"reason": {
"type": "script_exception",
"reason": "failed to run inline script [Float.parseFloat(doc['sessions'].value)] using lang [groovy]",
"caused_by": {
"type": "missing_property_exception",
"reason": "No such property: Float for class: 02f31d7c14f9b59a358a82c6bbf3853fa90738ec"
}
}
}
]
},
"status": 500
}
```

Why is it showing missing property exception? How to reference the 'session' field in the script?

**UPDATE:** the solution was to perform proper mapping before indexing , thanks to ***`Val`*** for the quick response.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why not indexing `sessions` as a numeric instead of string and 2) if 1) is not possible which version of ES are you currently running?

Comment: @Val large amount of data coming from other source where `sessions` field has string type and its not feasible to convert it to `integer` before indexing , also i am using 2.2.1 version of ES

Comment: By means of a proper mapping you could do it without modifying the client code.

Comment: Cool, maybe share your solution as an answer so other people can benefit ;-)